# Give wrong output

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import pandas as pd



options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

url = "https://www.askgamblers.com/online-casinos/reviews/casino-friday"
driver.get(url)

product=[]
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")


responsibles=soup.select("div#tabResponsible")

for responsible in responsibles:
    t1=responsible.select_one(".icon-deposit-limit-tool+ span")
    if "<span class="">Deposit Limit Tool</span>" in t1:
        print("yes")
    elif "<span class='strikethrough'>Deposit Limit Tool</span>" in t1:
        print("no")
```

I want my output in `yes or no` but everytime they give me `no` if there is `no line` on it then they print yes other wise they print no `as you see in pic`  kindly want I am do wrong there you suggest me solution these is the page link https://www.askgamblers.com/online-casinos/reviews/casino-friday

[image]

[image]

Comment: using bs4 you can check if the class id <span class=" strikethrough  "> or <span class=" "> and print the result as no or yes. Hope this helps

Comment: I am using the beautifulsoup and selenium both together in my code..

Comment: i don't have selenium installed so i can't do the entire code. if you see inside the tabresponsible div you can see that the text which have strikethrough have the span class as strike trough so you can check them by soup.find_all("p",{"class":"review-details__title"}) then iterate through this list and check if the span class has strikethrough or just blank.

Comment: not working.....

Comment: could you plz add the code that you just tried to the question.

Comment: Beautifulsoup will not work  ....so therefore I use beautifulsoup and selenium together

Comment: the code will be the same till you define soup and after that you have to add the changes that I said to get the desired output.

Comment: You see my code I already use beautifulsoup check in my code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Full Code**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import pandas as pd


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

url = "https://www.askgamblers.com/online-casinos/reviews/casino-friday"
driver.get(url)


soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")

responsibles = soup.find("div", {"id": "tabResponsible"})
responsibles = responsibles.find_all("div", {"class": "review-details__item"})
Title = []
Value = []
for i in responsibles:
    if (i.find("span", {"class": "strikethrough"})):
        Title.append(i.find("span").text.strip())
        Value.append("No")
        print(i.find("span").text.strip(), ": ", "No")
    else:
        Title.append(i.find("span").text.strip())
        Value.append("Yes")
        print(i.find("span").text.strip(), ": ", "Yes")
# dictionary of lists to Dataframe
mydict = {'Title': Title, 'Value': Value, }
df = pd.DataFrame(mydict)

# saving the dataframe
df.to_csv('output.csv')
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
Deposit Limit Tool :  Yes
Wager Limit Tool :  No
Loss Limit Tool :  No
Time/Session Limit Tool :  No
Self-Exclusion Tool :  Yes
Cool Off/Time-Out Tool :  Yes
Reality Check Tool :  No
Self-Assessment Test :  Yes
Withdrawal Lock :  No
Self-Exclusion Register Participation :  Yes
                                   Title Value        
0                     Deposit Limit Tool   Yes        
1                       Wager Limit Tool    No        
2                        Loss Limit Tool    No        
3                Time/Session Limit Tool    No        
4                    Self-Exclusion Tool   Yes        
5                 Cool Off/Time-Out Tool   Yes        
6                     Reality Check Tool    No        
7                   Self-Assessment Test   Yes        
8                        Withdrawal Lock    No        
9  Self-Exclusion Register Participation   Yes
```

Hope this helps. Happy Coding :)

Comment: how to get data save in csv file can you help me also......?

Comment: I Have changed the code to save the data as CSV. Plz upvote if you found this answer helpful

Comment: can we save data in these format in csv I shared picture in my question ...?

Comment: I add picture in my question you see now...

Comment: save the data in my csv like that can it save like that?

Comment: change df = pd.DataFrame(mydict) to df = pd.DataFrame(mydict).set_index('Title').T
 to get the desired output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250202/discussion-between-amysoj-louis-and-amen-aziz).